# Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]' in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Can I ask why I get this?

Couldn't match type `Char' with`[Char]'

Expected type: [String]

Actual type: [Char]

In the second argument of `(:)', namely`start'

In the expression: (show gm : start)

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    c <- parseArguments <$> getArgs
    input <- hGetContents stdin
    either print (handleGM input) c

handleGM input Config{..} = do
    handleGM <$> readFile tgrammer >>= either putStrLn (mapM_ putStrLn)
  where
    handleGM gm = do
        gm' <- parseGM gm
        case action of
             Simulate -> printGrammer gm' input

printGrammer gm@TGrammer{..} input =
    (show gm:start)
```

Data:

```
type TState = String
type TSymbol = Char

data TGrammer = TGrammer
   { neterminaly :: [TState]
   , terminaly :: [TState]
   , start :: [Char]
   , rules :: [Rules]
   }
  deriving (Show)

data Rules = Rules
    { from :: TSymbol
    , to :: String
    }
   deriving (Show)
```

Comment: `(show gm:start)` is really just `show gm : start`, which is the same as `(show gm) : start`, and it should probably be `show gm ++ start` instead, or better yet, `shows gm start`.

Comment: @DietrichEpp It doesn´t work. I just need print start from TGrammer but Idk how.

Comment: It would help if you added type annotations to your functions.  Is `printGrammer` supposed to be `Grammer -> String`?  Or perhaps `Grammer -> IO ()`?

Comment: Also note that since you have `deriving (Show)`, you can just `print` your `TGrammer` value out.

Comment: @DietrichEpp nope doesn´t work. 
    printGrammer :: TGrammer -> IO ()
    printGrammer gm@TGrammer{..} input =
     show gm start

Comment: @DietrichEpp if i have this  
`printGrammer gm@TGrammer{..} input =
 print start`
it doesn't work too. I get: 

`Couldn't match type `IO' with `Either String'
    Expected type: Either String ()
      Actual type: IO ()`

Comment: To clarify: Adding types here won't make your program correct.  Adding types helps us figure out what you are trying to do.  I have no idea what `printGrammer` is actually supposed to do, and adding types helps with that.  Once I know what it's supposed to do, I can help you with the errors in the program.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I just need create function which is called in `Simulate` (I mean `Simulate -> printGrammer` ) and this function print from `TGrammer` data about `nonterminals, terminals, start, ... ` but idk how can write it I am beginner with Haskell.
Types should be: `printGrammer :: TGrammer -> IO ()`

Comment: If you want `TGRammer -> IO ()` then you need to call functions like `putStr`, `putStrLn`, or `print`.  Remember that `show` returns a `String`, but does not print it out.

Comment: @DietrichEpp I tried it `printGrammer :: TGrammer -> IO ()
printGrammer gm@TGrammer{..} =
 putStr start` but i get error: `Couldn't match type ``IO' with ``Either String'
    Expected type: Either String ()
      Actual type: IO ()`

Comment: There must be a typo somewhere.  This works fine for me. 
 https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3bd490fdec45d30f2652407e981dc0f1

Comment: Idk why but it doesnt work

Comment: Sorry, "it doesn't work" isn't really enough information.  Usually, the bare minimum we need to know in order to help is two things: what, exactly, you want the code to do, and what the code actually does.

Comment: it doesn´t work i mean the same error `Couldn't match type ``IO' with ``Either String' Expected type: Either String () Actual type: IO ()` in the place where I call the function `printGrammer` (I mean `Simulate -> printGrammer gm'`)

Comment: Okay, the fact that it gives you the error where you called the function is important.  Annotate the type for `handleGM`, I don't know what it's supposed to do so I don't know what the correct type is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few things that are very weird about your code, so hopefully correcting them will help you solve your problem.

## Type Signatures

You should always include type signatures on your top-level bindings, as well as any non-trivial `where` or `let` bindings. These are my best guesses as to what you intended the types to be:

```
handleGM :: String -> Config -> IO ()
printGrammer :: TGrammer -> String -> IO ()
```

## Shadowed Binding

`handleGM` appears to be defined twice, once inside of itself in a `where` binding. This is *really bad* practice because it looks like you are trying to do a recursive call. You should consider renaming the internal function, or in this case, just writing it out in the do-notation, since its not recursive (and therefore doesn't need the `where` binding). In fact, you have misused `<$>`, which should only be used to map a pure function over an impure value. In this case, you are trying to use it to map an impure function of an impure value, which results in the confusing and not-what-you-want selection of `Either String ()` as the type for the inside `handleGM`.

## Operator overuse

It's best not to use `<$>` and `>>=` if your code isn't working, as it can hide what is actually happening, so write them out explicitly (do-notation) when you have problems like this.

Here is how I would revise `handleGM` so based on the above:

```
handleGM :: String -> Config -> IO ()
handleGM input Config{..} = do
  a <- readFile tgrammer
  b <- either putStrLn (mapM_ putStrLn) a
  gm' <- parseGM b
  case action of
    Simulate -> printGrammer gm' input
```

## [Char] doesn't match Char

This is because you used the cons operator `(:) :: Char -> [Char] -> [Char]`, but the first argument you gave it was already a `[Char]` (namely, `show gm`). What you probably want is `(++) :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]` which will put your two `[Char]` together into one longer `[Char]`. You probably also want to *print to the terminal* rather than just *compute a [Char]*, which means you need to use a function like `putStrLn :: String -> IO ()`. If these are accurate, here is what I would revise `printGrammer` to:

```
printGrammer :: TGrammer -> String -> IO ()
printGrammer gm@TGrammer{..} input = putStrLn (show gm ++ start)
```

## Miscellaneous

- You don't seem to actually do anything with `input`, so why bother passing it in at all?
- You might benefit from turning on `-Wall` by passing it as an argument when you compile. It turns on all the compiler warning so it will tell you if you probably made a mistake.
- You only have one case in your `case`. Why have the `case` there at all if it doesn't ever do anything different.
- `action` seems to be pulled out of thin air; where does it come from?